I'm having trouble to derive this first order logic problem
Hypothesis P1: $(A \leftrightarrow ((A \lor B) \rightarrow C))$
Hypothesis P2: $(B \leftrightarrow ((\lnot A \lor \lnot B) \rightarrow C))$
Theorem: $(C \land (A \land B))$
I'm trying to solve this in ProofWeb and I'm 69 steps in, the derivation tree looks massive and I think I'm not near the end. I tried to start the derivation with diferent aproaches but I always get stuck in the same spot. If anyone could help me, it would be much appreciated, if you guys are familiar with ProofWeb inference tactics, you can just write them and I will understand.

What does "A / B" mean?  It would be a lot more readable if you could use MathJax to typeset the expressions using standard notation.

Sorry, I didn't see it got disconfigurated, I used the html icons now, it should be fine

Break the theorem into three -- given $P1$ and $P2$, can you prove $A$? Perhaps by assuming the contrary that $\neg A$?

I don't get it, the first thing I did was introduce a conjunction, which left me with two subgoals: C and A∧B, I don't see how should I use ¬A to prove the first subgoal which is C.

There are three subgoals: $C, A, B$. I suggested to prove a different subgoal $A$ first, by contradiction and assuming $\neg A$.

@RafaelS.Bittencourt Can you [edit] the question, and include your diferent aproaches, the logic rules you are using and/or the ProofWeb inference tactics? Especially about ProofWeb, I don't know much about that tool.

$\def\oto{\leftrightarrow}\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}$
To prove $A$ given that $A\oto((A\vee B)\to C)$ and $B\oto((\neg A\vee\neg B)\to C)$ by RAA, we need to derive a contradiction under the assumption of $\neg A$.  A contradiction would be $A$ itself, and an equivalence for $A$ is given in the premise, so if we can derive $(A\vee B)\to C$ under the assumption, ...
$\fitch{A\oto((A\vee B)\to C)\\B\oto((\neg A\vee\neg B)\to C)}{\fitch{\neg A}{\fitch{A\vee B}{\fitch{A}{~\vdots\\ C}\\\fitch{B}{(\neg A\vee\neg B)\to C\\~\vdots\\C}\\C}\\(A\vee B)\to C\\A\\\bot}\\\neg\neg A\\A\\~\vdots\\C\wedge(A\wedge B)}
$
Once you derive $A$, the derivations for $B$ and $C$ should be easy.
